# How to work around Kendo UI ColorPicker validation bug for HEX colors?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-colorpicker

The Kendo UI [color picker](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/colorpicker/index) control allows entering HEX value manually.

But is has a bug: if you try to enter `#123XXX`, you will see then `#112233`

The reason is the Kendo UI color picker parses the first part of the color `#123` (which is a correct [short form](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_colors.htm)) and ignores the rest `XXX` symbols (which are not valid HEX symbols)

If you try another case: enter `#XXX123`, you will see the validation error (HEX value will be highlighted with red).

I need to validate correctly both cases and show the validation error. But I can not find a way to add custom validation to this control.

**Question:** do you know how to work around this bug and make Kendo UI color picker control fail on validating values like `#123XXX`, `#ADCXYZ`, `#19BW00` instead of cutting off the last 3 symbols and interpret the first 3 as a short HEX form?

Comment: I know Kendo UI team is monitoring questions with this tag. Any updates? It seems not as on Kendo site I neither got the answer http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/16027459-kendo-ui-colorpicker-validation-bug-for-hex-colors